# Dynamic datasets in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js, dynamic-arrays

I'm creating a React Component in typescript for each Chart type in chart.js. Most of it is working out fine. However, I've hit my first roadblock as I just remembered that you can have multiple datasets within a chart.

I have the following code for a Bar Chart

```
export class Bar extends React.Component<IBarProps, {}> {
  constructor(props: IBarProps) {
    super(props)
  }

  public render() {
    const className = classNames('bar-chart', this.props.className)
    const ctx = document.getElementById('bar-chart') as HTMLCanvasElement

    let bar: Chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: this.props.horizontal ? 'horizontalBar' : 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: this.props.labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: this.props.label,
            xAxisID: this.props.xAxisID,
            yAxisID: this.props.yAxisID,
            backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor,
            borderColor: this.props.borderColor,
            borderWidth: this.props.borderWidth
          }
        ]
      } as ChartData,
      options: {
        elements: { rectangle: { borderSkipped: this.props.borderSkipped } }
      }
    })

    bar.update()
    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <canvas
          id="bar-chart"
          width={this.props.width ? this.props.width : '400'}
          height={this.props.height ? this.props.height : '400'}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
  // private push() {
  //   const dataSets = this.props.dataSets
  //   dataSets.forEach(dataSet => {new Object(label: this.props.label,)})

  //   return dataSets
  // }
}
```

The issue is that the way I've set it up, it'd only support a single dataset. What i need is that for each dataset that is defined, create an object for it and push it into the datasets array. However I'm not a Javascript expert nor typescript expert.

Would anyone be able to show me how to setup the dynamic datasets array? If you need more info see the [Bar Chart Docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html)

Comment: set data value as a dynamically changeable object e.g. instead of `data:[1,2,3]`, do `data:barData`. After whatever event you want to listen to, change `barData` object and call `bar.update()`

Comment: Is this what you are looking for:
 http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html?

Comment: And that's why you should always read the docs XD